# Finding unique triplets from list in Python

Tags: python, permutation, nested-lists

I am writing some research script in python and I have a list of 9 elements:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I would like to find all combinations of subsets containing the 3 elements (and NOT the 3 element sets themselves), so for example:

```
a_new = [ [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ] ],
          [ [2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,1] ],          
          [ [3,4,6],[1,2,8],[5,7,9] ], etc.... ]
```

- the elements are not repeated in the subsets
- the sets [3,2,1] and [1,2,3] are the same set and are not unique

Have you perhaps faced such a case, or some Python library will handle it?

Greetings

Comment: Does the order of the 3 subsets matter?

Comment: Looks like OP wants all possible 3-group length-3 subsets of `a` such that the union of each group of 3 produces `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

# pick 3
for c_out in combinations(a, r=3):
    s_out = set(c_out)
    # pick the next 3 from the those elements that are not already picked (i.e not in s_out)
    for c_in in combinations(a - s_out, r=3):
        # there only 3 elements left so only one way to pick
        rest = tuple(a - (s_out | set(c_in)))
        print(c_out, c_in, rest)
```

**Output** *(partial)*

```
(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6) (8, 9, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 7) (8, 9, 6)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 8) (9, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 9) (8, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 6, 7) (8, 9, 5)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 6, 8) (9, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 6, 9) (8, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 7, 8) (9, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 7, 9) (8, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3) (4, 8, 9) (5, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (5, 6, 7) (8, 9, 4)
(1, 2, 3) (5, 6, 8) (9, 4, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (5, 6, 9) (8, 4, 7)
(1, 2, 3) (5, 7, 8) (9, 4, 6)
```

You can read more about set operations (union, difference) in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: Your solution solves exactly what I've looked for! Thank you very much. I hope that it will help others in the future as I've looked literally everywere.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `itertools` built-in module

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

combination = list(combinations(a, 3))
```

this output in tuple and you can transform to list easily.

Comment: I'm not sure this matches the expected output

Comment: this solution is not complete, the final solution has to consist of list of lists, where each top-level list has to contain each number only once